# Angular animations using the query function

Tags: angular, animation

I want to animate menu items' color change using the Angular animations query function instead of applying the animation trigger on each li > a

Below is the usage in the template.

```
`<ul [@changeMenuColor]="isNavBarWhite ? 'white' : 'transparent'">
   <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
 <ul>
`
```

And below is the animations config in the component's decorator. I have left out the rest of the code unrelated to the animation for brevity.

```
@Component({
      ...
        trigger('changeMenuColor', [
         transition('white => transparent', [
           query('li > a', [
             style({
              color: 'white'
            }),
            animate('0.2s ease-in')
        ])
       ]),
       transition('transparent => white', [
        query('li > a', [
          style({
              color: 'blue'
            }),
            animate('0.2s ease-in')
        ])
      ]),
    ])
     ...
 })
```

The animation is not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

We need to maintain the change of the `css` in the `state` rather than in the `transition`.

And I think it would be sufficient to target `ul` parent element instead of `li > a` as the state wouldn't allow a child element target. However, if we still want to target `a`, then it's best to specify `the target element`

Here's how we can do it.

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger('changeMenuColor', [
      state(
        'white',
        style({
          color: 'black',
        })
      ),
      state(
        'transparent',
        style({
          color: 'blue',
        })
      ),
      transition('white => transparent', [
        query('li > a', [animate('0.2s ease-in')]),
      ]),
      transition('transparent => white', [
        query('li > a', [animate('0.2s ease-in')]),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cbcupc?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for your reference. Also [angular guide on animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations) should help you in detail.